# ¿Como excluir filas de acuerdo a un criterio SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Buen Dia.
Una vez mas vengo buscando su apoyo para realizar una consulta.
Tengo la siguiente DB:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta DB es para observar el progreso del material de producción (el progreso se puede ver en las ultimas 4 columnas donde se registra el status)
Como podran observar, se usan "○" y "△", estos simbolos significa "Proceso completado" y "Proceso pendiente" respectivamente, una vez que todo los procesos son completados las columnas de Progress1-Progress4 estaran con el simbolo "○".

Las celdas van cambiando de acuerdo al progreso, lo que quiero lograr es una consulta la cual me regrese las filas que contengan por lo menos un "△" ("Proceso Pendiente"). Ya que una vez que estan completados no me interesa ver la fila ya que todo esta completo, me gustaria ver algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta que realice fue la siguiente:

```
SELECT
      [ACTUAL_FROM]
      ,[ACTUAL_TO]
      ,[UNIT_NO]
      ,[PLAN_VOLUME]
      ,[PROGRESS1]
      ,[PROGRESS2]
      ,[PROGRESS3]
      ,[PROGRESS4]
     FROM [Data].[dbo].[Progreso] WHERE PROGRESS1 not like '○' AND PROGRESS2 not like'○' AND PROGRESS3 not like '○' AND PROGRESS4 not like '○'
```

Por obvias razones lo que consegui con este codigo fue que me ocultara todas las filas que tuvieran un '○'("Proceso completado") y pues no es lo que quiero lograr.
Me gustaria saber si hay algun ciclo o alguna manera de que esto pueda tener solucion.
Les agradezco de antemano y quedo al pendiente.

Comment: ¿Y si buscas _por el lado positivo de la vida_? Más bien preguntas por los registros donde PROGRESS1 es pendiente OR PROGRESS2 es pendiente OR... PD. Pero qué necesidad de mezclar la presentación (los simbolitos) con loque se guarda en BD (en vez de mapear estados a números, 1 pendiente, 2 completado, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Utiliza el operador de comparación de igualdad `=`, pues se busca una coincidencia exacta y no hace falta usar el operador `like`. Esto, gracias al optimizador de SQL seguramente no hace diferencia para la computadora, pero si hace que la consulta sea más fácil de comprender para un humano.
- Luego, la lógica de la cláusula `where` casi puede expresarse en lenguaje común y corriente, así que vamos a evolucionarla primero en lenguaje natural y finalmente escribirla en SQL:

  - Las filas que contengan por lo menos un `'△'`, también puede decirse:
  - Las filas donde una o varias de las columnas de progreso sea igual a `'△'`, que también puede decirse:
  - Las filas donde la columna `Progress1` sea igual a `'△'` o la columna `Progress2` sea igual a `'△'` o la columna `Progress3` sea igual a `'△'`, etc.

Aquí hemos llegado al punto donde, traducir esto a SQL resulta trivial:

```
  where progress1 = '△'
     or progress2 = '△'
     or progress3 = '△'
   ... etc;
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la explicacion tan detallada, de esta manera me quedo demasiado claro, ya hice la prueba en mi query con esta modificacion y me funciono a la perfeccion!